# Data Access Layer (DAL) design

Tags: c#, data-access-layer

I'm using .Net enterprise library data access application block for my Data Access layer  design.

In my Category DAL class, I've methods like :

GetProductsInCategory(int CatId), GetAllProducts, GetCategories, etc.

My question is: where do I put this line of code ?

```
DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("MyDB");
```

shall I put it in every method above or shall I have a base class which would return Database object to my DAL class.

Also, shall I keep these DAL class methods as static?

Answer (score 3):

I prefer a base class that returns common objects like connection, in you example Database.

Here is reference to desing Data access Layer : [.NET Application Architecture: the Data Access Layer](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/.net-application-architecture-the-data-access-layer/)

I use Microsoft Enterprise Library Data Access Application Block. It does most of the things mentioned here. but common stuff like connections or transactions goes to my base class.

[image]

> The DataServiceBase class provides
>   common data access functionality like
>   opening a database connection,
>   managing a transaction, setting up
>   stored procedure parameters, executing
>   commands, and so forth. In other
>   words, the DataServiceBase class
>   contains the general database code and
>   provides you with a set of helper
>   methods for use in the individual data
>   service classes. The derived data
>   service classes use the helper methods
>   in the DataServiceBase for specific
>   purposes, like executing a specific
>   command or running a specific query.

Comment: If you have a base class, then you don't need a factory method since derived classes can just access the `protected Database _myDatabase`.

Comment: @Ian Quigley : yes, you will need to instantiate your "protected Database _myDatabase", so you need the factory class at your base class' constructor.

Comment: thanks for ur tips..i will have all my DAL classes derived from a base class DBManager.This class will have a protected method called GetDatabase() which will have code:
return DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("MyDB");
And my method in derived class would look like:...(contined in the next comment)

Comment: public DataSet GetProductsInCategory(int Category) 
{Database db = base.GetDatabase();
DbCommand dbCommand = db.GetStoredProcComman("GetProductsByCategory");
db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "CategoryID", DbType.Int32, Category);
return db.ExecuteDataSet(dbCommand);} 
does this DAL design look ok?

Answer (score 1):

thanks for ur tips..i will have all my DAL classes derived from a base class DBManager.This class will have a protected method called GetDatabase() which will have code: return DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase("MyDB"); And my method in derived class would look like:..

```
public DataSet GetProductsInCategory(int Category) 
{
Database db = base.GetDatabase(); 
DbCommand dbCommand = db.GetStoredProcComman("GetProductsByCategory"); 
db.AddInParameter(dbCommand, "CategoryID", DbType.Int32, Category); 
return db.ExecuteDataSet(dbCommand);
}
```

does this DAL design look ok?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking at using SubSonic for DAL and object generation. It implements Microsoft's Application Block but gives you simple (and robust) query capabilites like;

```
SubSonic.Query qry = new SubSonic.Query(Usr.Schema);
qry.SetSelectList(Usr.Columns.UserPkid);
qry.QueryType = SubSonic.QueryType.Select;
qry.AddWhere(Usr.UsernameColumn.ColumnName, SubSonic.Comparison.Equals, Username);

using (IDataReader reader = qry.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("Fetched User Pkid [" + reader[Usr.Columns.UserPkid].ToString() + "]");
    }
}
```

And of course it implements the [ActiveRecord](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern) pattern so the object classes have the .Delete(), .Add(), .Get() type methods.